# How do I change the name of a model generated by scaffold cleanly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I have a model called `ModelA` that I want to rename to `ModelB`.

I generated `ModelA` by doing `rails g scaffold ModelA`. That generated the model, controller, views, specs, routes, etc.

How do I cleanly change the name of `ModelA` given that I have setup associations, join tables, etc.

Also, how do I do it such that my local environment is in sync with Heroku when I push.

I feel like it is very easy to mess this up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have released your code to an environment where you can't drop tables, you will just have to hand write migrations. No out-of-the-box rails way for the same.

Comment: It's not just about the tables. It's about that attribute being called/accessed on all the views/controllers/tests/models/etc. Is there an easy way to do that - other than 'global find & replace'?

Comment: afraid not! a lot depends on the code editor you are using as well.